# passing a comparative array to filter function in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to filter out values for an array by passing another array to the filter function.

```
x = [1,2,3];
y = [2,3];

var n = x.filter(filterByArray);

function filterByArray(element, index, array, myOtherArray){
   // some other code
});
```

What is the best way to pass "y" to the "myOtherArray" prototype in the function?

Comment: What is the expected output?\

Comment: I've tried .bind() but it didn't work for me.  Output doesn't really matter, say I want to filter out duplicate elements, this is just an example.  I've found ways to do it without the .filter(), but I would rather the .filter() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the second parameter of [`.filter(callback[, thisArg])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to set its `this` value to something "useful" such as your second array

```
function filterByArray(element, index, array) {
   return this.lookup.indexOf(element) > -1;    // this.lookup == y
};

var x = [1,2,3],
    y = [2,3];

var result = x.filter(filterByArray, {lookup: y});
console.log(result);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tgdxoLmf/)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the signature of the callback but you can have a separate class that takes the other array as parameter:

```
function MyFilter(otherArray) {
    this.otherArray = otherArray;
}

MyFilter.prototype.filterByArray = function(element, index, array) {
    // you can use this.otherArray here
};
```

and then:

```
x = [1,2,3];
y = [2,3];

var myFilter = new MyFilter(y);
var n = x.filter(myFilter.filterByArray);
```